# Why is the Microsoft Graph Planner APIs suddenly failing for external guest users in a Team?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner

From approximately March 23 2020 Microsoft Graph Planner apis like https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/tasks/TC41-x8azkKX-ibO17qtJpYAHGAB starting throwing 401 for external guest users with the following error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">\r\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\"/>\r\n<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>\r\n<style type=\"text/css\">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:\"trebuchet MS\", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"header\"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id=\"content\">\r\n <div class=\"content-container\"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>\r\n  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "33a1c8d0-60b3-46ab-807a-da5a8d776151",
      "date": "2020-04-13T07:51:57"
    }
  }
}
```

The Microsoft Graph call has `Group.ReadWrite` permissions.
The same user can access the task fine through Microsoft Planner with this url: https://tasks.office.com/meetingdecisions.com/Home/Task/TC41-x8azkKX-ibO17qtJpYAHGAB

Why did this suddenly start happening?